# How does generic works for nested Lists

Tags: java

I have a meeting centre class, each meeting centre contains 1..n meeting rooms and each room has 0..n reservations.

I want to iterate through the meeting centres, for everyone create a sublist with all its reservations and then add the sublist to the list with all reservations from all meeting centres

```
public List<ArrayList<Reservation>> findAllReservations() {
    List<ArrayList<Reservation>> allReservations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (MeetingCentre mc : this.getMeetingCentres()) {
        ArrayList<Reservation> currentMCReservations = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MeetingRoom mr : mc.getMeetingRooms()){
            if (mr.getReservations().size() > 0){
                currentMCReservations.addAll(mr.getReservations());
            }
        }
        if (currentMCReservations.size() > 0) {
            allReservations.add(currentMCReservations);
        }
    }
    return allReservations;
}
```

I want to export this data into JSON, and when I try to work with the allReservations List, the generic get "lost" and I get an exception "Object cannot be converted into Reservation"

Comment: When you deserialize you have to specify what kind of object the deserializer is retrieving. I'm not sure what you're using right now, but I think it might just be defaulting to key,value pair a.k.a. a map. Which you are trying to convert to a Reservation, which of course cannot be done. I think we're missing some code here to fully answer this question.

Comment: Which library are you using to export to Json?

Comment: Guess you'll want to look up Type Erasure: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best simple solution is to use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonList = gson.toJson(list_name);  // converts list to json
    System.out.println(jsonList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a List of ArrayLists?

```
public String getAllReservationsJSON() {
    List<Reservation> allReservations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (MeetingCentre mc : this.getMeetingCentres()) {
        ArrayList<Reservation> currentMCReservations = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MeetingRoom mr : mc.getMeetingRooms()){
            if (mr.getReservations().size() > 0){
                currentMCReservations.addAll(mr.getReservations());
            }
        }
        if (currentMCReservations.size() > 0) {
            allReservations.addAll(currentMCReservations);
        }
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    return gson.toJson(allReservations);
}
```